# Why do Tifa and Scarlett have a slap-fight?

Tags: video-games, final-fantasy

This has been bothering me since I was a child.

In the 1997 game Final Fantasy 7, there's a point in the second disk where:

> Meteor has just appeared in the sky. Tifa and Barret are due to be executed as scapegoats for it and Junon is being attacked by a Weapon. Tifa escapes the gas chamber through a hole created by the Weapon attack. Then runs down Junon's cannon to escape. Scarlet, of Shinra, catches up and the two fight.

This fight is unique in the game, however, because it's a slap-fight with added dialogue. However this seems very out of character. Tifa is known to be a skilled martial artist. This means that even without her weapons, she'd be a formidable fighter.

Why, then, do they stand there having a rather pathetic slanging match with slaps? Wouldn't Tifa just do some MMA and throw her off the cannon?

Comment: It's supposed to be funny. Which in fairness, it is.

Comment: Before being a skilled fighter, Tifa is a highly sexualized young female character and it was 1997. When she fights another girl, she fights like a girl.

Comment: There is a time for fighting, and there is a time for slapping.

Comment: Misogyny. The answer is misogyny.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a slap is more of an insult than an attack. Or, as the wiki says, “The purpose of a slap is often to humiliate, more than injure.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapping_(strike)

Tifa was tapping her foot impatiently as Scarlet was talking, which was impolite, so Scarlet slapped her. Tifa wasn’t genuinely threatened by Scarlet, but she was angered by the slap, so she slapped her back.

I don’t think Tifa would throw her off the cannon... she’s not a murderer. Then again... final fantasy handles death inconsistently. The heroes fight & kill a lot of monsters, which I guess is okay for some reason, but they sometimes fight & kill enemies who look human. In 7 Remake, some human enemies visibly turn into mako (lifestream) after you defeat them, suggesting unambiguously that they died and, thus, that the heroes killed them.

It IS really bad optics that this slap fight was between two women.

Comment: "It IS really bad optics that this slap fight was between two women." What else? Males get into fistfights.

Comment: Just to cross-examine your theory: Scarlett is chasing Tifa to the end of the cannon, a long way over the sea, with soldiers (not SOLDIERs) in tow. She’s definitely under threat of being shot or forced off the end. Character wise: I’m pretty sure that Tifa’s pacifism was never addressed or even suggested before the remake. I like the remake, but I think we need to acknowledge that the two stories and their characters are not compatible. Elements of the remake do not add depth to the original, they’re a separate entity.